# C++ erase from set of pointers does not work?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

I created a set of pointers, and tried to erase one member in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    Node(int val){
        this->val = val;
    }
    int val;
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
};

struct comp{
    bool operator()(const Node* a, const Node* b) const{
        return a->val<=b->val;
    }
};

int main() {
    set<Node*, comp> s;
    Node* n1 = new Node(1);
    s.insert(n1);
    Node* n2 = new Node(2);
    s.insert(n2);
    Node* n3 = new Node(1);
    s.insert(n3);
    
    for(auto it=s.begin();it!=s.end();it++){
        cout<<(*it)->val<<",";
    }
    cout<<endl;

//print out 1, 1, 2
    
    s.erase(n1);
    
    for(auto it=s.begin();it!=s.end();it++){
        cout<<(*it)->val<<",";
    }
    cout<<endl;

//still print out 1, 1, 2 after deleting n1

    return 0;
}
```

It seems that after erasing the pointer, the printing result still shows it. Can someone help me explain this? If I want to erase the pointer from the set, what is the proper way to do it?

Comment: `<=` does not satisfy the requirements of a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings).  Namely `!(a <= b) && !(b <= a)` will never be `true`, and so no elements will ever compare equal.  Use `<` instead.

Comment: `a->val<=b->val` violates the *Compare* requirements in [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

Comment: `comp::operator()` doesn’t return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comp functor does not meet the `[Compare][1]` requirement

```
struct comp{
    bool operator()(const Node* a, const Node* b) const{
        a->val<=b->val;
    }
};
```

> Compare is a set of requirements expected by some of the standard
> library facilities from the user-provided function object types.
>
> The return value of the function call operation applied to an object
> of a type satisfying Compare, when contextually converted to bool,
> yields true if the first argument of the call appears before the
> second in the strict weak ordering relation induced by this type, and
> false otherwise.